# How to approach this method chaining in TypeScript? Error ts(2339)

Tags: typescript, types

I'm receiving a ts(2339) error in attempting to use method chaining on flexible methods that can be used to both get and set a private properties.

Suppose I have the following class:

```
export default class A {

  private _propertyA!: number;
  private _propertyB!: string;

  constructor() {
    this._propertyA;
    this._propertyB;
    this._init();
  }

  private _init() {
    // Do something in initializing the class.
  };

  public getPropertyA() {
    return this._propertyA;
  }

  public getPropertyB() {
    return this._propertyB;
  }

  public propertyA(value?: number): number | this {
    if (value === undefined) return this.getPropertyA();
    this.setPropertyA(value);
    return this;
  }

  public propertyB(value?: string): string | this {
    if (value === undefined) return this.getPropertyB();
    this.setPropertyB(value);
    return this;
  }

  public setPropertyA(value: number): this {
    this._propertyA = value;
    return this;
  }

  public setPropertyB(value: string): this {
    this._propertyB = value;
    return this;
  }

}
```

I have "getters" via `get` prefix on methods and "setters" via `set` prefix on methods. Then there are "shorthand" methods that are flexible that can either get or set a private property depending on whether or not an argument is provided to the method.

When I attempt to use the following method chaining, it results in a TypeScript error (see code comments):

```
import A from './a';

// Results in the following TypeScript error:
const a = new A()
  .propertyA(100)
  .propertyB('value');
// Property 'propertyB' does not exist on type 'number | A'.
// Property 'propertyB' does not exist on type 'number'.ts(2339)

// Results in the following TypeScript error:
const a = new A()
  .propertyB('value')
  .propertyA(100);
// Property 'propertyA' does not exist on type 'string | A'.
// Property 'propertyA' does not exist on type 'string'.ts(2339)

// This works but we are not chaining.
const a = new A()
  .propertyA(100);

// Works as expected.
const a = new A()
  .setPropertyA(100)
  .setPropertyB('value');
```

TypeScript Version 4.6.3

It seems to me that TypesSript is not recognizing the return type is `this` when there is no argument provided to these methods and the `value` parameter is `undefined`. And the error is introduced in method chaining.

**Is there a bug that I'm overlooking or how can this be adjusted to make these shorthand methods work?**

Many thanks!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use overloads:

```
  public propertyA(): number;
  public propertyA(value: number): this;
  public propertyA(value?: number): number | this {
    if (value === undefined) return this.getPropertyA();
    this.setPropertyA(value);
    return this;
  }
```

Then when you call without parameters it returns a number, and if you provide a value it's `this`:

```
new A().propertyA(); // number

new A()
  .propertyA(100)
  .propertyB("foo") // assuming you did the same for propertyB
```